# Matrix Transformation

Tags: matrices, geometry

Consider a triangle that has vertices at $A(1, 2)$, $B(2, 3)$ and $C(4, 2)$. Reflect this triangle in the line through the origin which is inclined at $30^\circ$ to the positive $x$-axis. Find the vertices of the transformed triangle.

To solve this question, I rotate this triangle through $-30^\circ$ first and then reflect it about $x$-axis and then rotate through $30^\circ$. I am not sure if this way is correct.

Comment: Your approach should give the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

The general approach for finding a 2D matrix for a transform $T(p)$ is to see what happens when you transform $e_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ and $e_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ through $T$.  The transform matrix $M$ is the 2 by 2 matrix $M = \begin{bmatrix} T(e_1) & T(e_2) \\ \end{bmatrix}$.

So what is $T(e_1)$ in your problem? Flipping $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ around the $30^o$ line gives a unitvector at an angle of $60^o$, or $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \over 2 \\ \sqrt 3 \over 2 \end{bmatrix} = T(e_1)$.

Flipping $\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ about the $30^o$ line gives a unit vector at an angle of $-30^o$, or $\begin{bmatrix} \sqrt 3 \over 2 \\ - 1 \over 2 \end{bmatrix} = T(e_2)$.

So altogether your transform is $M = \begin{bmatrix} T(e_1) & T(e_2) \\ \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \over 2 & \sqrt{3} \over 2 \\ \sqrt{3} \over 2 & - 1 \over 2 \end{bmatrix}$.

All that is left is to compute $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \over 2 & \sqrt{3} \over 2 \\ \sqrt{3} \over 2 & - 1 \over 2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \over 2 & \sqrt{3} \over 2 \\ \sqrt{3} \over 2 & - 1 \over 2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix}$, and $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \over 2 & \sqrt{3} \over 2 \\ \sqrt{3} \over 2 & - 1 \over 2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 4 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$.

... of course we skipped the most important step, the first step.  The first step was to see if there actually is a matrix that represents your transform $T$.  The matrix is correct if $T$ is a *linear* tranformation, meaning it has 2 properties:

- $T(P + Q) = T(P) + T(Q)$, the transform of the sum of two vectors is the vector-sum of the transforms
- $T(cP) = cT(P)$, scaling a vector by any factor $c$ then transforming it is the same as transforming and then scaling by $c$

Since we are only reflecting across a line, it's not too hard to visualize that both of these properties hold, so the matrix $M$ actually does represent $T$.